# [Android System]How to create folder in storage/emulated/0 before/during the boot phase?

Tags: android, operating-system, filesystems

I need to create a folder in storage/emulated/0 then perform mount operation.

First I try to do it in /system/core/rootdir/init.rc

```
mkdir /storage/emulated/0/avtmp
mount tmpfs tmpfs /storage/emulated/0/avtmp size=10m
```

but it doesn't work at "on init" or "on post-fs-data",and mkdir work by using other path,such as

```
mkdir /system/test
```

So I think the question is the timing of /storage/emulated/0 created
I also tried to do this in /system/core/rootdir/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD += ; mkdir /storage/emulated/0/avtmp
LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD += ; mount -t tmpfs -o size=10m tmpfs /storage/emulated/0/avtmp
```

It doesn't work too.

I have search for help by google or other ways,but all the answers I get are about Application develop not System.Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Now this problem has been solved.
storage/emulated/0 mounted by "vold" process not "init" process,so we should do mkdir and mount in VolumeManager.

Code in /system/vold/VolumeManager.cpp

```
int VolumeManager::linkPrimary(userid_t userId) {
    std::string source(mPrimary->getPath());
    if (mPrimary->getType() == android::vold::VolumeBase::Type::kEmulated) {
        source = StringPrintf("%s/%d", source.c_str(), userId);
        fs_prepare_dir(source.c_str(), 0755, AID_ROOT, AID_ROOT);
        //MYCODE BEGIN
        std::string mountPath = StringPrintf("%s/avtmp", source.c_str());
        fs_prepare_dir(mountPath.c_str(), 0755, AID_ROOT, AID_SDCARD_RW);
        std::vector<std::string> cmd;
        cmd.push_back("mount");
        cmd.push_back("-t");
        cmd.push_back("tmpfs");
        cmd.push_back("-o");
        cmd.push_back("size=10m");
        cmd.push_back("tmpfs");
        cmd.push_back(mountPath.c_str());
        android::vold::ForkExecvp(cmd);
        //MYCODE END

        .......//other codes
    }
}
```